# Deploying Django App to Heroku Cant load Staticfiles

Tags: python, django, web, heroku

I have successfully deployed my django app to heroku. but for some reason, they cant load the templates and staticfiles.

my directories are as such:
eximia (project directory)

- eximia: **init**.py asgi.py settings.py wsgi.pyurls.py
- web: templates, static: web: style.css, images: (all the images are in this folder)

and the rest of the files are normal typical django app files.

my settings.py are as follows:

```
Django settings for eximia project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'sy4a^dk+1%2!g2@4s$2ihk0^9%!9or&+ycy2#0a^*qqhdksk#t'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    "eximia-denim.herokuapp.com"
]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'web',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'eximia.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'eximia.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Im very new to django and this is sorta my first website. So if theres any help i would really appreciate it!! thank you! :D

Answer (score 1):

To serve static files in Heroku you must use Whitenoise.
if you don't know how to use that check Heroku documentation [Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a global **static** folder that are not tied to any particular app.
if you have static folder inside each app, django will not have a problem to collect static files and put them inside **staticfiles**, but in your case you need to tell django that there is global **static** folder that is not tied to particular app to collect static files from it:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Comment: hi yeah i tried this. and an error comes up when i tried to git push heroku master. the error is No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_1a24849a/static'.